# iOS 7 date time zone issue

Tags: ios, timezone, ios7

I am converting a NSDate object to string format. using `GHKit`. Internally its using `NSDateFormatter` `stringFromDate`

```
[NSDate date] gh_format:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz" useWeekday:NO]


- (NSString *)gh_format:(NSString *)format useWeekday:(BOOL)useWeekday {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:format]; 
    NSString *formatted = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self];
    if (useWeekday) {
        NSString *specialWeekday = [self gh_weekday:dateFormatter]; 
     formatted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", specialWeekday, formatted];
    }
    [dateFormatter release];
    return formatted;
}
```

This method works fine with iOS 5, 6 producing the following output

```
2013-10-10 10:43:44 GMT+05:00
```

However iOS 7 produces something like this which my web server is unable to parse

```
2013-10-10 10:43:44 GMT+5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ` for your date format.

See http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns for more info